# openerp: internal server error on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I have just installed the new OpenERP 8.0 unto my system replacing the existing OpenERP 7.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. I had already downloaded this on my Ubuntu laptop at home and it works very well and wanted to do the same in my office server.

Steps I undertook:

1. sudo apt-get remove openerp
2. Went to /etc/apt/sources-list and edited it, added the line for to add the new erp dependencies
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install openerp
5. restart system
6. open browser for localhost:8069

But I get an internal error.

Please assist me in solving this problem. If this is a postgresql role problem, please assist on how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: can you please post internal error? I think might be issue of addons path.

Comment: Whats the error message.?

Comment: i think you should go for a new fresh installation of Odoo. http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-install-odoo-from-github.html might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Create the odoo user in postgres:

```
 sudo -u postgres createuser -s odoo
```

I had the same issue after an install of Odoo 8 on Debian. I read about postgres user creation in [Odedra's blog](http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-install-odoo-from-github.html). Creating the odoo user in postgres fixed the server error, the odoo interface appeared on http://localhost:8069.

Creating a postgres user was not specified in the [Odoo installation page](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html).

Comment: suggested a change to this documentation here: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/compare/8.0...paul4forest:patch-1

Comment: I installed odoo 9 clean using apt-get and had the same issue.  The above solution worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe  there are more than one process running.

> try to kill all of postgresql process by identifying them with ps -A... 
>    restart your machine