# internal server error odoo

Tags: linux, postgresql, odoo, openerp-8

after installing odoo on debian, exactly on VMware using these commands
1/ apt-get update
2/ apt-get upgrade
3/ wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
4/ echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
5/  apt-get update
6/ apt-get install python-pydot
7/ apt-get install odoo

and when I lunch it on firefox using localhost:8069, the message internal server error appears
ps: service odoo status   and  service postgresql status . both are active

Comment: 1. You should really read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2. The answer to your problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869176/openerp-internal-server-error-on-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: thank you, all I did to fix it is killing postgresql process few times , then restart my machine ..... finalllly. localhost:8069 is working

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and here is the solution:
- try to create new Postgres user, you can do that as follows:

> open ur terminal and type: $ `su - postgres` if asked for a password just press Enter "if ur running under parrot or kali os open the root terminal" 
>   then type: $ `createuser odoo --pwprompt` , it'll ask for password type ur pass and confirm it

I hope it works for u

Comment: thank you so much. i did that a year ago and it did work... now I'm on odoo 10. regards